# How to correctly send a message to the Queue - Javascript / AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have a simple lambda that receives an SQSEvent.
I have setup a DLQ (dead letter queue) in case the lambda fails to process the message.

```
const lambdaHandler = async (event: SQSEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {

  if(!event || !event.Records || !event.Records.length || !event.Records[0].body) {
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Event and event body is required' })
        };
    }
```

I think I am handling this incorrectly.
I send an HTTP response and I handle error response like an API.

What should be the correct way to send the message to the DLQ?

Comment: Did you add the DLQ to your [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-dlq) or to the SQS [queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html)?  If your Lambda has a queue event source, you need to put the DLQ on the \*queue\*.  Then follow @MarkB's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the Lambda function returns an error response, the message will be moved to the SQS queue. The easiest way is to throw an exception. If there is a possibility of receiving more than one SQS message per Lambda event (if you have the message batch size set to a value greater than `1`) then you should look at returning a [message batch response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), in the format:

```
{ 
  "batchItemFailures": [ 
        {
            "itemIdentifier": "id2"
        },
        {
            "itemIdentifier": "id4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Best practice would really be to always return a response in that format, and it would simply be an empty list if there were no errors.